# Laravel 5.5 is refused to install npm in project

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm-install, git-bash

I get the following error when I execute `npm install` in Laravel 5.5:

> npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace
>   it, following the guidelines at
>   https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5 npm ERR! Unexpected
>   end of JSON input while parsing near '...{},"dist":{"shasum":"'

I visited that URL but couldn't resolve the problem.

Comment: try `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Please post the full error and which node version and npm version are you using? The warning is a red herring, as it's just a deprecation warning, the real error is cutoff and has to do with a JSON parse error of some sort and will almost certainly be a versioning error

Comment: Thanks @JaredChu, I later figured out that it was due to network issues. I could install it and everything I needed after solving the network issue.